# How to find the Gateaux derivative when F(a)=b

Tags: real-analysis, gateaux-derivative

How can i approach finding the Gateaux-derivative $F'(a)(r)$ where $F(a)=b$? I tried $F'(a)(r)=\frac{F(a+rt)-F(a)}{t}=\frac{F(a+rt)-b}{t}$ but I'm not sure how to continue or how to simplify this.

Comment: What is your function $F$?

Comment: I forgot to add the following: For each $a \in \ell^p(\mathbb{R})$, let $F(a)=b$, where $b$ is the sequence with components $b_i=sin(a_i)$ (for$\hspace{0.5mm}i\in\mathbb{N}$). We also have that $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $\ell^p(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of all sequences $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_{\ell^p}<\infty$ where $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_{\ell^p}=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\left\vert a_i \right\vert^p\right)^{1/p}$.